# styles.less background image transition in a div

Tags: css, less

I have a div with a background png repeated, I want to give a transition of 0.4s with styles.less, if I use a colour works, but if I use an image on the background doesn't work why?
This is my code:

```
.transition_bg{
    transition-property: background; /*standard*/
    transition-duration: 0.4s;

    -webkit-transition-property: background; /*Safari e Chrome */
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s;

    -o-transition-property: background;      /*Opera*/
    -o-transition-duration: 0.4s;

    -moz-transition-property: background;    /*Firefox*/
    -moz-transition-duration: 0.4s; 
}

#navigation li
{
    margin: 0;
    width:126px;
    height:40px;
    padding-left:0px;
    padding-right:0px;
    list-style:none;
    float:left;
    background:url(../img/header/bg_nav.jpg) top left repeat-x;
    .transition_bg;
}

#navigation li:hover{
    background:url(../img/header/bg_nav_hover.jpg) top left repeat-x;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSS transitions will not fade in / out background images (unless anyone can correct me).

If you're convinced you need to do this, perhaps you could use two containers each with a background image in, but when you hover the opacity of one is set to 1 and the other 0, whereas the default would be the opposite. This would achieve your requirements, but you'd have to deal with another element in your DOM, which might cause problems.

I was going to provide an example, thinking you wanted the background to apply to a generic container, but as you're wanting to do this inside a list item you'd have to increase your code substantially.

Comment: Guve me an example please.. It can be a solution if is impossible to do in other mode. Thanks a lot